# How to Call web services secured with apache rampart by Spring-integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, interceptor, ws-security, rampart

I'm working on a project that call a web service and made some decision based on it. Now the web service is secured with Apache rampart with this security-policy.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SigEncr"
            xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
            xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                    sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireThumbprintReference/>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                    <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss10>
            <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
            <sp:SignedSupportingTokens
                    xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken
                            sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
            <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                <ramp:user>tatTestUser</ramp:user>
                <ramp:encryptionUser>server1</ramp:encryptionUser>
                <ramp:userCertAlias>client1</ramp:userCertAlias>
                <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>com.asansoft.callbackHandler.PasswordCallbackHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
                <ramp:signatureCrypto>
                    <ramp:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin">
                        <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</ramp:property>
                        <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">/home/key/signedKey/client.jks</ramp:property>
                        <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">password</ramp:property>
                    </ramp:crypto>
                </ramp:signatureCrypto>
                <ramp:sslConfig>
                    <ramp:property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore">/home/key/client.jks</ramp:property>
                    <ramp:property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword">123456</ramp:property>
                </ramp:sslConfig>
            </ramp:RampartConfig>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

How can adopt my old service based on this security configuration?
I use outBoundGateWay to call a web service.
Can I use apache rampart in Spring-Integration?
Should I use an Interceptor?